# Spring.NET attributes based configuration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, spring.net

I have my asp.net MVC application and I need to configure spring objects with attributes like [Service], [Repository], [PostConstruct] and [Autowired] (In Java i can do this with  option in context-config file), but i cannot find any information how i can do this...

I've found a lot of docs about Spring.CodeConfig, but all of them shows how use [Configuration] and [Definition] attributes on config classes...

So, is it possible to configure Spring.NET to scan some assemblies for [Service] and other attributes and automatically add them to context?

Comment: afaik, this is not possible out-of-the-box. You might be interested in [spring-net-configuration-fluently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558638/spring-net-configuration-fluently/5275531) too.